# Fabric apps migration to Firebase reached limit

Tags: ios, firebase

So we have a white-label applications - currently 30+. We use Fabric's Crashlytics SDK and their web dashboard. Everything is working fine until Firebase want us to migrate all applications from our Fabric account to Firebase.

Everything seems to be working during the migration (using the Migrate apps button in Fabric) at first. Until we migrated 30 apps to the Firebase, now we can't migrate the other apps! due to the limit Firebase set.

Any suggestion how can we migrate the remaining apps to Firebase? TIA

Comment: Contact Firebase support directly: https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly 30 is the limit per Firebase Project - Maybe after creating another one you could import them there! :)

Comment: thanks! that's what we did we created another Firebase project and migrate the remaining app into it.